# Unpack a buffer which is packed by perl with template "N/a* N/a*" in golang

Tags: perl, sockets, go, pack

I am new to perl. I need to write a golang code which read UDP package sent from a perl UDP socket client. Basically, the perl client packs data using the template "N/a* N/a*" like the following:

```
$them = pack($sockaddr,&AF_INET, $data_port, $broadaddr);
$actual_data = pack("N/a* N/a*", $string1, $string2);
send(S,$actual_data,0,$them) || die $!;
```

My question is:

1. What does "N/a* N/a*" actually means? A simple explanation would be helpful. How two strings are actually packed?
2. How i can write a similar packing function in golang given two unicode strings; and if I got a packed buffer sent from perl UDP client, how i can write a corresponding function "in golang" to unpack it. Is there any library which can handle this so that I can use golang on par with perl for socket programming.

Comment: See [perlpacktut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlpacktut.html) and the [documentation for `pack`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html).

Answer (score 2):

From [the pack documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html):

- `N` is an unsigned long in network format
- `a` is a string with arbitrary binary data
- `*` is a repeat count that uses up the rest of the characters in the string
- the `/` notes that you're packing a length of the item and then the packed item.

You can write a small program to check it out:

```
use v5.10;
my $first  = 'dog';
my $second = 'parrot';

my $packed = pack "N/a* N/a*", $first, $second;

say $packed;
```

Run it and you won't see the number, but you can hexdump it to see everything:

```
$ perl5.22.0 pack.pl
dogparrot

$ perl5.22.0 pack.pl | hexdump -C
00000000  00 00 00 03 64 6f 67 00  00 00 06 70 61 72 72 6f  |....dog....parro|
00000010  74 0a                                             |t.|
00000012
```

There's a `00_00_00_03` in front of `dog` and a `00_00_00_06` in front of `parrot`. Those are the lengths of the packed strings. This probably means the other side scans the string by reading the number, then grabbing that number of succeeding octets.